# Почему цикл возвращает не все данные в БД?

Tags: php, база-данных, for

Клик на `input` открывает календарь, где пользователю предлагается выбрать дату. Далее, когда пользователь нажал на день месяца, я отправляю `ajax` запросом на сервер `json` строку состоящую из часов (`["10:00","18:40"...]`) по услуге, которую выбрал юзер. Сервер должен мне вернуть из БД информацию, а именно найти в БД на каждый час из `json` строки кое что. Однако есть нюанс - параметр дополнительно отправляемый на сервер. `allow` может быть `true` или `false`, что означает разрешить запись на этот час по этой услуге или нет. Если параметр `true`, я должен посчитать количество людей на этот час в этот день или, если `false` вернуть только те часы, которые не забронированы в выбранный день.

У меня по каким-то причинам возвращается часть информации, например при `allow === true` только на первый час из массива `json` строки, а про второй параметр я вообще молчу... Сам по себе я фронт и бэк знаю худо да бедно.

```
<?php

    $date = $_POST['date']; // выбранная юзером дата для поиска в бд
    $serv = $_POST['serv']; // название услуги
    $type = $_POST['type']; // формат услуги
    $allow = $_POST['allow']; // сам параметр (строка)
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'booking');
    $json = json_decode($_POST['json']); // часы по услуге
    $query = "SELECT*FROM orders";
    $table = $db->query($query);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($json); $i++){

        $find = 0;

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){
            if($row['serv'] === $serv and $row['type'] === $type and $row['date'] === $date and $row['time'] === $json[$i]){
                if($allow === 'true'){$find = $find + +$row['folk'];}
                else if($allow === 'false'){$find = 'find_time';break;}
            }
        }

        if($allow === 'false' and $find !== 'find_time'){echo '<div class="booking_time f"><p>' . $json[$i] . '</p><p></p></div>';}
        else if($allow ===  'true'){echo '<div class="booking_time t"><p>' . $json[$i] . '</p><p data-folks="' . $find  . '/чел"></p></div>';}
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Цикл пробегает по количеству элементов массива $json, но считывает результат запроса к БД. Мне кажется должно быть

```php
for($i = 0; $i < $table->num_rows; $i++){
```

Comment: Я не очень понял. Можете подробнее? Я вставил ```$table = $db->query($query);``` в цикл ```for``` перед циклом ```while``` и всё заработало. Можете объяснить, что произошло?